# What are the specific conditions that require a frenzy roll?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

So, I think, any exposure to a Bane can cause  frenzy roll (unless otherwise stated?), but it talks about starving, social and injury, where can I find rules for what exactly constitutes these things? is 1 bashing enough to cause a resist frenzy roll? what's starving? page references and quotations appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for Frenzy, including a list of stimuli that can have an effect on the Resolve + Composure roll to resist, are on pages 103-105 of **Vampire: The Requiem 2nd Edition.** The list on page 104 says, "Under the right circumstances, any of these things could be a provocation to frenzy," so you can use that as a guideline tempered by Storyteller choice.

- Being wounded (to any degree) is a slight provocation; being down to your last three boxes is a greater one.
- "Starving" is described as having 2 or less vitae in your Blood Pool; "Hungry" is 4 or less.